# Making argv an integer array

Tags: c++, argv

When we define the parameter's of the `main` function body how come it cannot be defined as an integer array or can it?

If is can, how would I assign an integer value out of there into a variable.

Comment: you can't. you need to parse it from string

Comment: It could be done but nobody's going to bother. Converting strings into integers (or anything else you need) is trivially simple, so why break a _very well established_ standard just to save somebody one or two lines of code?

Comment: It's just the way the interface is defined. There are many ways you could pass information between the command shell and the program, but the method chosen was a list of strings. It's a reasonably good choice.

Answer (score 4):

The standard about `main`:

> N4140, § 3.6.1 [basic.start.main]/2
>
> It shall have a declared return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

So an implementation *can* offer `int main(int argc, int argv[])`. But I know of none that do, so you'd have to write your own. It's far easier to convert the strings to integers.